# Storing a List with floats inside a List

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to store multiple `float[][]` that contain `float` values inside of something because I'd like to shorten my code.

I currently have a function that multiplies two `float[][]` with another.
I have many `float[][]` to be multiplied.

I saw someone do it similar to this:
`for(PVector v : points) {};`

I don't have that PVector class or whatever it is. So what could I use instead?
Maybe there is a way to combine all those `float[][]` into a structure.

My code:

```
    whateverstructuregoeshere = {
        float[][] p1 = {{200}, {100}, {0}};
        float[][] p2 = {{200}, {300}, {0}};
        float[][] p3 = {{400}, {100}, {0}};
        float[][] p4 = {{400}, {300}, {0}};
    };

    for(float[][] v : whateverstructuregoeshere) {}
```

Comment: So... are you asking about lists or arrays?

Comment: @Turing85 If the difference between lists and arrays is that arrays are 2d and lists 1d, I'd ask for  arrays.

Comment: what is your question ? can you show some input and output example

Comment: Probably `List<List<Float>>`. Anyway you should rephrase your question.

Comment: Neither `Lists` nor `Arrays` are multidimensional.  They are both `single dimensional` objects which may hold instances of other `single dimensional` objects.

Comment: @Varvalian this only half true. You can "simulate" more dimensions by using, e.g. `List<List<Float>>`, as pointed out by @PeterMmm. On a side-note: java does not have multidimensional arrays. A `float[][]` is an "array of arrays of `float`s", which is different from multidimensional arrays in C, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `float[][][]` or better yet a `List<Float[][]>`. (Got to pick a List implementation though, like `ArrayList` or the like)

Comment: How can I insert something into that `List<Float[][]>`? Doing `List<Float[][]> points = {p1, p2};` doesn't work (illegal initializer)

Comment: Do `List<Float[][]> points = new ArrayList<Float[][]>();` and then `points.add(p1); points.add(p2);`. If you wanna do `points = {p1, p2};` you'll have to use a `float[][][]`

Comment: points.add(p1) returns an error (identifier expected) I will just use float[][][] then.

Comment: I got it to work with `Float[][][]` so it's fine. Thanks for your help